# Fusion DB in google maps

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

Could you please explain me what is the different between KML and fusion tables?

when it is possible to use them ?

what is the different between them ?

does I have DB for KML and fusion table ?

How i can find public data for KML and fustion tables ?

Does it have DB for cities for each country include the latitude ?

Regards

Yossi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't answer all your questions.  But the major advantage for Fusion Tables over KML is that all the geographic features in a Fusion Table (points, lines, polygons) are converted to tiles by the Fusion Table engine. This means that is can greatly increase the GMap display performance when you have many geo-graphic feature, e.g. up to 100K point markers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Broadly speaking, KML provides a language for describing geographic information like points, lines and polygons.

Those descriptions can be in a KML file and then viewed on Google Earth or in a KML layer in the Google Maps API.

Or, those descriptions can be imported to Fusion Tables, viewed on a map, embedded in a website or accessed via Fusion Tables Layer in the Google Maps API.

Public Fusion Tables with resources you can re-use can be found in the [help center](http://support.google.com/fusiontables/bin/topic.py?hl=en&topic=27018) or by [searching](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/search?hl=en&q=country%20boundaries).

You may also find this page useful: [Working with geographic data](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/developers_guide#Geo).